# await async function C#

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, asynchronous

I am developing a Silverlight project using WCF.I need to call a function from WCF after another WCF function has finished.Here is my code :

```
Int32 id = Convert.ToInt32(((TextBlock)dataGrid1.Columns[0].GetCellContent(dataGrid1.SelectedItem)).Text.ToString());
        Service1Client obj = new Service1Client();
        obj.DeletePersonAsync(id);

        //Wait for delete operation

        obj.GetPersonListCompleted += new EventHandler<GetPersonListCompletedEventArgs>(ListPeople);
        obj.GetPersonListAsync();
```

How can i do that?

Comment: So why don't you use `await obj.DeletePersonAsync(id);` ?

Comment: I tried but await is not pre-defined in default silverlight project.Do i need to add something like reference?

Comment: What version of .Net are you targeting?

Comment: I'm using .NEt 4.0 framework

Comment: [The await / async keywords were introduced in Visual Studio 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156528.aspx)  -  What version VS are you using?

Comment: Visual Studio 2010.Is there any plug-in or something?

Comment: I don't think so, you would need to upgrade I think.  In order to further answer this question, we would likely need to see the implementation of `DeletePersonAsync()`.

Comment: Is The code above running in Silverlight or in the WCF Service?

Comment: @caa This code is running in Silverlight.

Comment: so why can you not do something like this :  obj.DeletePersonCompleted += (s,e) => { obj.GetPersonListCompleted += new EventHandler<GetPersonListCompletedEventArgs>(ListPeople);
        obj.GetPersonListAsync(); };

Comment: Uh,I haven't known about that usage.I will try it.Thanks a lot.

Comment: okay, let me know how it goes. You just need to embed the second WCF service call inside the completed event handler of the first WCF service call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the function "GetPersonListAsync" int the callback of obj.DeletePersonAsync(id) function. The code will be soemthing like as follows:

```
   private void somefunction()
{
    Int32 id = Convert.ToInt32(((TextBlock)dataGrid1.Columns[0].GetCellContent(dataGrid1.SelectedItem)).Text.ToString());
    Service1Client obj = new Service1Client();
    obj.DeletePersonAsyncCompleted += new EventHandler<DeletePersonCompletedEventArgs>(PersonDeleted);

    obj.DeletePersonAsync(id);
}


    private void PersonDeleted(DeletePersonCompletedEventArgs serviceResponse)
    {
     //Wait for delete operation

    obj.GetPersonListCompleted += new EventHandler<GetPersonListCompletedEventArgs>(ListPeople);
    obj.GetPersonListAsync();
    }
```